# How to warn before sending email if Subject: is empty

Tags: email, message-mode, notmuch

If I hit `C-c C-c` in `message-mode` (I use `notmuch`) in order to send an email I've composed, I want to be warned if the Subject: header is empty.  E.g. "Really send without Subject? (yes or no)"

When composing new email I fill in the Subject after I have written the body because only then I know exactly what Subject: matches this emails contents best.  Sadly I often forget to actually set the Subject and with message-mode the email is sent without Subject:.

I searched online, but I'm astonished that this does not seem to be a recurring topic let alone an already answered FAQ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to hook into `message-send-hook`:

```
message-send-hook is a variable defined in ‘message.el’.
Its value is nil

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Hook run before sending messages.
This hook is run quite early when sending.
```

For example:

```el
(defun my-confirm-empty-subject ()
  "Allow user to quit when current message subject is empty."
  (or (message-field-value "Subject")
      (yes-or-no-p "Really send without Subject? ")
      (keyboard-quit)))

(add-hook 'message-send-hook #'my-confirm-empty-subject)
```

Comment: Great, I tested this and it works.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gregor Updated to call `message-field-value` instead of `message-fetch-field`, which generally worked but could lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the function to `message-send-hook`, as suggested by Basil, I ended up adding the very same function to `message-send-mail-hook` instead. For some reason (or none?) `message-send-hook` was always invoked twice for me (and it would ask me twice to confirm). `message-send-mail-hook` is called once only.

Comment: Are you sure it's the "Subject" question being asked twice, and not a different question each time?  Do you by any chance use queued/deferred message sending?  Because that's the only other place I see `message-send-hook` called.  If you can reliably reproduce the issue, I suggest reporting it via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.